# Dropping rows in a multi-index data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have this df:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'tic': ['IBM', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'IBM', 'AAPL'],
               'industry': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                'price': [np.nan, 5, 6, 11, np.nan],
                'shares':[100, 60, np.nan, 100, np.nan],
                'dates': pd.to_datetime(['1990-01-01', '1990-01-01', '1990-04-01', 
                                             '1990-04-01', '1990-08-01'])
                })

temp.set_index(['tic', 'dates'], inplace=True)
temp.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Which yields:

```
                industry  price  shares
tic  dates                             
AAPL 1990-01-01        B    5.0    60.0
     1990-04-01        B    6.0     NaN
     1990-08-01        B    NaN     NaN
IBM  1990-01-01        A    NaN   100.0
     1990-04-01        A   11.0   100.0
```

How can I create a `new column` in the data frame that shows the number of observations for each tic. So, the new column will like this:

```
        New column
AAPL    ... 3
        ... 3
        ... 3
IBM     ... 2
        ... 2
```

Comment: please don't change your question - it invalidates existing answers...

Comment: @MaxU My bad. Won't repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [.groupby(level=0)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [.filter()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) methods:

```
In [79]: temp.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3)
Out[79]:
                industry  price  shares
tic  dates
AAPL 1990-01-01        B    5.0    60.0
     1990-04-01        B    6.0     NaN
     1990-08-01        B    NaN     NaN
```

Answering your second question:

```
In [83]: temp['new'] = temp.groupby(level=0)['industry'].transform('size')

In [84]: temp
Out[84]:
                industry  price  shares  new
tic  dates
AAPL 1990-01-01        B    5.0    60.0    3
     1990-04-01        B    6.0     NaN    3
     1990-08-01        B    NaN     NaN    3
IBM  1990-01-01        A    NaN   100.0    2
     1990-04-01        A   11.0   100.0    2
```